# hiding method in java inheritance

Tags: java, oop, static-methods, overriding, method-hiding

I have two class as following:

```
public class Car {
    public static void print() {
        System.out.println(getWord());
    }

    public static String getWord() {
        return "CAR";
    } 
}

public class BMW extends Car {
    public static String getWord() {
        return "BMW";
    } 
}

// main method
public static void main(String args[]) {
    BMW.print();
}
```

After I run above sample, this output is printed:

> CAR

My question is: Why is the method `getWord()` not overriden?

Comment: your methods are `static`, `Car.print` references `Car.getWord`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to characteristics of static methods,

1. we cannot override static methods.
2. If a method is static and you declare same method in the inherited class with the same as of base class it will not be hidden.

Please check below rules from Java Doc :

Overriding: Overriding in Java simply means that the particular method would be called based on the run time type of the object and not on the compile time type of it (which is the case with overriden static methods)

Hiding: Parent class methods that are static are not part of a child class (although they are accessible), so there is no question of overriding it. Even if you add another static method in a subclass, identical to the one in its parent class, this subclass static method is unique and distinct from the static method in its parent class.

Answer (score 7):

Static methods cannot be overridden because method overriding only occurs in the context of dynamic (i.e. runtime) lookup of methods. Static methods (by their name) are looked up statically (i.e. at compile-time).

Comment: OP is talking about "method hiding", not overriding.

Comment: As tim mentioned below, If you want to hide the print() method, then you can make the method with private access.

Comment: You don't to explain that to me, instead you should add this to your answer so OP can read that. Also don't forget to credit Tims answer if you use parts of his answer in your edit.

Comment: Now after the update of the question. My answer is good to go :)

Comment: Yes, because someone changed "hiding" to "override" and badly some reviewers don't care about reviewing correctly :(.

Answer (score 2):

In Java: fields & `static` methods do not adhere to dynamic/runtime polymorphism. When you call `BMW.print()`, it inherits the static definition from `Car`. Being a `static` function call it refers to `Car.getWord()`

Answer (score 2):

The `getWord()` method in class `BMW` is not called when you call `BMW.print()` because `static` methods are associated with a `class`, not an instance of a class.  Once you make the call to the `static` method `BMW.print()`, several things are required:

- All method calls made from `BMW.print()` must *also* be `static` methods if they are defined inside the `BMW` class
- There is no concept of inheritance, i.e. calling the `getWord()` method will not propagate to a child class.  The reason for this is that `getWord()` is a `static` method associated with the `Car` class itself.

If you really wanted to get your current code to print `"BMW"`, you could try the following (which isn't very good design):

```
public class Car {
    public static void print() {
        System.out.println(BMW.getWord());
    }

    public static String getWord() {
        return "CAR";
    } 
}
```